# Could not find a part of the path on windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I deployed mvc-3 application on windows azure. In my application i am uploading the file an save it in the `App_Data/DownloadedTemplates` folder.

```
  var path = Server.MapPath("~App_Data/DownloadedTemplates");
```

my application is running on staging environment currently. When i uploaded file , it shows me an exception in the browser :

**Could not find a part of the path 'F:\sitesroot\0\App_Data\DownloadedTemplates\B.htm_2c77cdfd-c597-4234-bd1e-29ca0a9b8d0e.htm'.**

I am using `Server.MapPath` to locate the path of App_Data on the server, now why this exception ?. Can anybody tell me the problem ?

Comment: do App-Data and the folder DownloadedTemplates exist on the server? they're not created automatically.

Comment: yes when i was deploying my project it was in my project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this in a Windows Azure application. In Windows Azure you should use [LocalResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.localresource.aspx) (reserved space on a dedicated disk) for saving temp files on the disk, this is the only place where you should store data.

Here is an example of how you would access such a LocalResource (name and size can be configured in the VS project):

```
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("DownloadedTemplates");
```

Don't forget that data in LocalResources might disappear (when the machine crashes for example). If you really want to persist your data, you should be using Windows Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: doh! Thanks Sandrino. So simple and yet iI totally overlooked this.