# LocalResource not available after publishing mvc4 to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I've a very simple application built in MVC4. This application allow the users to upload a file, and the application generates an output.
This app works great locally, but when I publish to azure (by right click -> publish), I get a less descriptive error. I've figured out that the error was because in the code, we accessed to a server relative path, and that is not possible in azure. So I've found a way to solve that in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687903/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-on-windows-azure), that says that I should use LocalResource, rather than Server.MapPath. That make sense for me, but so far, I'm struggling with the suggested line.

```
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("DownloadedTemplates");
```

I'm not able to get it working, and also can't get a proper error. BTW I'm not sure how to enable the error log in azure :(
So, after going deeper in MSDN, I've seen that [I should configure the Local Storage Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758708.aspx), but as I've created a local MVC4 project, I can't find where I should configure this.

I need to be able to store a temporary file in the application (hosted in azure).

- Did someone faced with this problem?
- Anybody knows how to enable the Local Storage Resource in a project like that?

TIA! 
Milton Rodríguez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling a while, I've ended up using Windows Azure Tools.
The steps:

1. Add a new project
2. Under Cloud category, select Windows Azure Cloud Service.
   Note that if you don't have this option, an option to install the needed SDK will be shown. Install it first.
3. Name it properly :)
4. New Windows Azure Cloud Service window will appear, select the role that fits your needs. In my case, I choose ASP.Net MVC4, and then removed it.
   Note that you can edit the name of the created role at the right.
5. In the Roles folder of your new project, select Add, and then Web Role Project in solution. Your project will be an option to add.
6. You can remove the other role in the folder, the web project created in step 4, and also the folder ending in Content (ie. WebRole1Content). Basically, you can remove the created assets, but the Azure Service, and link the service to your project.
7. You're almost done. Follow [this link](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/learning-azure-local-storage-with-me/) to configurate your local storage :)
8. Now you're done!