# Relative path from Service Website on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

I have a Azure Cloud Service with a WCF web role.  I am trying to access a file within App_Data and I don't want to hardcode the path.  I've tried using:

`System.Web.HostingEnviroment.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfile");`

as well as turning on aspNetCompatibilityEnabled and using `Server.MapPath()`

but both ways return:

> d:\windows\system32\inetsrv\App_Data\myfile

The actual location of the file is:

> E:\sitesroot\0\App_Data\myfile

Is there any way I can access this file short of hard-coding the path?

Comment: Borrowing from [this thread][1], consider using LocalResources instead.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687903/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-on-windows-azure

Comment: Yea, I know this is not the correct way to do things... but I'm requiring on a Library written by someone else that is closed and the way it was written would require me use the regular file system.   I'll probably go back to them and ask to rewrite this component anyways. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After deployment azure cloud service will deploy the application to a VM. So accessing the files from any subfolder with relative path does not change.

You can read the file without mapping virtual file. You can load the file passing just below file path.
"/App_Data/myfile"