# Directory not found exception for worker role localstorage

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, azure-blob-storage

On a worker role onStart event, I'm selecting a json file on azure blobstorage and downloading it to worker role's localstorage..

```
  blockBlob2.DownloadToFile(RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("WorkerRoleStorage").RootPath, FileMode.Create);
```

I'm receiving the System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException as shown below..

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024893
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Arnab\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\006f5676-9c7e-4984-bbe7-83abd71f6726\directory\WorkerRoleStorage\'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToFile(String path, FileMode mode, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
       at WorkerRole1.WorkerRole.OnStart() in d:\uax\CollectorTest1\AzureCloudService1\WorkerRole1\WorkerRole.cs:line 64
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRole(RoleType roleType)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
  InnerException:
```

But when I try to acccess the path shown in error 'Message', I'm able to reach there on my m/c..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use Local Storage Resources which is a reserved directory in the file system of the virtual machine in which an instance of a role is running. Code running in the instance can access the local storage resource when it needs to write to or read from a file.

MSDN Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974419.aspx

Related post: [Could not find a part of the path on windows azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687903/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-on-windows-azure)

Comment: That's the problem.. RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("WorkerRoleStorage").RootPath is throwing the directory not found exception..