# How to store library's resources in azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating mobile service that use [NMeCab](https://osdn.jp/projects/nmecab/) library, it need dictionary files which is referred from code using `Server.MapPath`

```
DicDir =  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"../App_Data/ipadic")
```

When I ran service locally it work fine but when I published service on azure `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path` was thrown

I googling and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687903/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-on-windows-azure) on SO, it is recommended to use `LocalResource` to refer to local storage but I think this should be used in case uploading service which is not in my case.
So, How can I store this resources in azure?

Comment: You have not given enough information to diagnose a specific problem.  Are you using Mobile Services or Azure App Service Mobile Apps?

Comment: @AdrianHall I'm confused when you asked me, I'm using Mobile Services to expose Web API so that I can consume  it from my android application.

Comment: Thanks - there are two types of mobile apps and many people get the two confused.  Will answer.

Answer (score 1):

The LocalResource area (also known as App_Data) is for any temporary data.  If you are storing permanent data, you should use one of the Azure Storage APIs to handle it.  However, temporary data can be stored on disk.  As the topic you referenced suggested, you should use LocalResource:

```
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("DownloadedTemplates")
```

The reason your path does not work is that it assumes that the current directory is in a specific place and hence App_Data is relative to that.  This is just not the case on Mobile Services.  Use LocalResource instead.

Reference to LocalResource with an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getlocalresource.aspx

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I think I answered you wrong answer, I'm using this service on Azure [cuptured from azure portal](http://upic.me/show/57047513) Do you call this Azure App Service Mobile Apps?

Comment: No - that is Azure Mobile Services. The LocalResource should still work.

Comment: I got `InvalidOperationException: the role environment has not been initialized` and `InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.` when I tried to use RoleEnvironment, I already set this project as Startup project in VS, How can I fix this?

Comment: And if I manage to use RoleEnvironment, from what I understand, when I publish Mobile Services project(which I download from GET STARTED section in Azure to modify it) from VS to Azure every file and subdirectory in App_Data will be uploaded to LocalResource area, so, Do I have to specify directory as `DicDir = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("ipadic").RootPath` without specify <LocalResources> in ServiceDefinition.csdef(I can't find this file)?