# Azure static files System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application running on Azure. The application sends various emails - both in plaintext and HTML formats. I have created a subfolder in our `Resources` folder, called `EmailTemplates`, where I store all the HTML and TXT templates. An example path could be:

`\src\WebProject\Resources\EmailTemplates\Welcome.html`

I access the file in my `EmailService.cs` class in the following manner:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "EmailTemplates", "Welcome.html");
var htmlTemplate = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
```

This works great when running on local environment both on IIS and Kestrel. However, when deployed to Azure, I get an IO error message:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Resources\EmailTemplates\Welcome.html'.
```

I have found a similar question on StackOverflow, but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688090/7414119) is almost 6 years old. I am not sure, whether it still applies since Azure has changed significantly in the past couple of years. I was also looking at official documentation [(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1) [(2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x), but I did not find anything special about Azure.

What is the correct way to store and retrieve email templates (and other static files) in ASP.NET Core and Azure?

Comment: and did you make sure that your static file is part of the deployment? (Copy to output folder -> always)? Is the local relative path "Resoruces" part of your project?

Comment: It turned out to be the case. Please, could you write an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your static files are part of your project.

And mark them explicitly as content and `Copy to output folder` -> always.

Comment: I had to explicitly 'publish' the html files as well as setting the above, then they appeared and worked.

Answer (score 1):

When we publish our .Net Core web app to azure, all of its contents are placed under this path [D:\home\site\wwwroot] except static files.

According to your description, we need to create the `Resources` folder under wwwroot in our project. Then we can access the file using below code after we publish to azure:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Resources", "EmailTemplates", "Welcome.html");
```

We can look over the directory information of our project in azure via KUDU: [Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

**Update:**

We need to allow our `Resources` folder would be copied to publish directory at csproj file as below:

```
<Content Include="Resource\*">
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me in my case ?i do not have root folder in my project

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436224/directorynotfoundexception-error-thrown-by-code?noredirect=1#comment122729361_69436224

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER! It worked great for me after much struggle. Just add  the code Lee shows to your .csproj file in your ASP.NET project and it works perfectly in Docker containers! Btw...I tested this solution thoroughly by creating various tests, including an endpoint in my WebAPI Core project that streams a PDF located inside my static subfolder off the web root. After building my Docker image and running a Docker Container it copied over both the static folder and its static files in the browser and worked great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

No matter where the files are in the project, if you make your files "Embedded ressource" and "Copy if newer" in the property, when publish, folder and files will be created !

[image]